# Cannot create "Code Signing" OID - Get "OID value is Invalid" on Android

Tags: c#, security, xamarin.android, code-signing, x509

I want to set the `ApplicationPolicy` on a `X509Chain` to allow for Code Signing. When I do this on a Windows application it works fine, But on Android I cannot create the OID representing "Code Signing"

I have the following code

```
X509Chain certChain = new X509Chain()
Oid oid = Oid.FromFriendlyName("Code Signing", OidGroup.EnhancedKeyUsage);
certChain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(oid);
```

This gives a runtime error 
`System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The OID value is invalid.`  when running on Android.
When I use the same code on a .NetFrameWork application on windows it works fine.

Does the c#/xamarin code not know what the "Code Signing" oid is? Is there a way around it?

Comment: What if you do `Oid oid = new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", null);` instead?  In general, looking things up by friendly name is bad (for one, it can lead to problems when different languages are in use)

Comment: @bartonjs I think this will give the same error (I cant test right now) I have also tried `certChain.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Add(new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3"));`